# Texture mapping on a cylinder in C (building a raytracer)

Tags: c, algorithm, mapping, textures, raytracing

This is my first question here so I hope I'm doing it right.

I'm trying to build a raytracer for a school project, and I'd like to add some texture mapping to my basic shapes. I already did it for the sphere and it worked perfectly, this is the algorithm I used (UV mapping):

```
d = vector3d_normalize(vector3d_sub(hit->point, object->position));
u = 0.5 + atan2(d.z, d.x) / M_PI * 0.5;
v = 0.5 - asin(d.y) / M_PI;
```

For the cylinder, I can't find any algorithm so I'm trying different things but I can't make it work. Actually, it works fine for a cylinder when it's fixed at (x: 0, y: 0, z: 0) but from the moment I'm moving it in space, the texture looks stretched.

For the code at this moment, it's the following:

```
d = vector3d_sub(hit->point, vector3d_mult(object->position, ray->direction));
u = 0.5 + atan2(d.z, d.x) / M_PI * 0.5;
v = d.y / M_PI;
v = v - floor(v);
```

Cylinder in (0, 0, 0): [image: img]

With translation: [image: img]

I'm stuck so if you have any idea, it could help me a lot!

Comment: 1. what info about the cylinder you got: (Basis vectors,transform matrix + radius + height, base point + axis + radius)? 2. What is the input (ray intersection point , ray start point + direction) ? to enable texturing: 1. compute intersection 2. convert it to cylinder [LCS] local coordinate system 3. compute `u,v` as you did but from `x,y,z` in [LCS]

Comment: The line: `d = vector3d_sub(hit->point, vector3d_mult(object->position, ray->direction));` is a bit puzzling for me - what is supposed to happen there?

Answer (score 0):

Here's some pseudo-code from Jamis' Buck's *The Ray Tracer Challenge* (highly recommended):

```
    // Based off of pseudocode from Jamis Buck: http://raytracerchallenge.com/bonus/texture-mapping.html
    // Input: point on the cylinder. The cylinder is assumed to be of radius 1, centered at the origin and parallel with the y axis.
    // Output: (u,v) with u and v both between 0 and 1.
    // u will vary from 0 to 1 with the azimuthal angle, counter-clockwise.
    // v will vary from 0 to 1 with whole units of y; note that the cylinder will have to be scaled by PI in the y axis to prevent stretching
    map_cylinder_point_to_uv(point: (x: float, y: float, z: float)) -> (float, float) {
        // compute the azimuthal angle, -PI < theta <= PI
        float theta = arctan2(point.x, point.z);
        // convert from radians to units
        // -0.5 < rawU <= 0.5
        float rawU = theta / (2 * Constants.PI)
        // convert to correct scale, and flip it so that u increases with theta counter-clockwise
        // 0 <= u < 1
        float u = 1 - (rawU + 0.5);

        // v will vary from 0 to 1 between whole units of y
        // Use whatever modulus method or operator your language has to gauarantee a positive value for v.
        // It's different for every programming language: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#In_programming_languages
        float v = point.y % 1

        return (u, v)
    }
```

Your problem may have to do with the fact that you are placing a square texture on a cylinder, and the length of the texture applied to the side of a cylinder will be some multiple of 2 PI (the circumference of a circle). You may be able to fix your issue by simply scaling the cylinder in the y axis by PI or 2 PI.

If you don't want to be limited to cylinders of particular dimensions, and you have a texture that can be repeated like a checker pattern, then you can scale v to prevent stretching. Replace the `v` calculation above with this line, instead:

```
// let v go from 0 to 1 between 2*pi units of y
let v = point.y % (2 * Constants.PI) * 1 / (2 * Constants.PI);
```

I'll also note that these days there's also a separate stack exchange for computer graphics that might be of more help than SO: https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/.